# Upper limit of human comfort in higher atmospheric pressures?

Tags: planetary-science, pressure, humans

At what atmospheric pressure, assuming an earth-like atmospheric composition, do humans start to feel uncomfortable? I am not asking for the max survivable pressure, but the point where long term human comfort is affected. I know at lower atmospheric pressures people have trouble breathing and doing exercise, and apparently even [fertility rates are affected](https://academic.oup.com/humrep/article/37/Supplement_1/deac107.718/6620483), but what's the equivalent for the opposite?

Comment: "feel uncomfortable" - is hard to quantify. But the pressure itself can increase (very slowly) to 100 atmospheres or more. The main question is what mixture of gases or oxygen-rich liquid you could breathe at this pressure. Normal air becomes toxic at 7-8 atmospheres. So, in your case, it is not a question of 'comfort under pressure'. It is a question of being comfortable after being drowned in oxygen-rich liquid.

Comment: Among other issues with saturation diving is messing with the sense of smell and the fact that food cools off fast due heavier atmosphere, a question if these count as 'comfort' issues. There are also normally humidity issues that impact both comfort and health but unsure if that is pressure, or a side effect of these pressures normally being encountered underwater.

Comment: Scuba divers (saturation or not) seem to have no "comfort" issues going to quite high pressures, but they do need to breathe special gas mixes.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance Normal air should not be used with a pressure of more than about 4 to 5 bar, especially when used for more than some hours. A nitrogen narcosis is possible.

Comment: @Uwe - so what did I do wrong again? I did write: "Normal air becomes toxic at 7-8 atmospheres"

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance only 701 meter or 70 bar were achieved: Comex Hydra X (Hydra 10) simulated dive in an onshore hyperbaric chamber. 100 at or more is wrong.

Comment: @Uwe - We are talking about different things (regarding 100 atmospheres). You are talking about [helium, oxygen and hydrogen gas mixture]. I was talking about [oxygen-rich liquid] that was tested on mice and on human (unconfirmed data). At 100 atmospheres or more, only [oxygen-rich liquid] would be possible for breathing.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't want the limits for pure oxygen, or helium or hydrogen. I am solely looking for the answer for the limits of human comfort in an atmosphere identical to earth's atmospheric composition, just with higher pressure. I am sorry if I explained it poorly.

Comment: @GoingFTL - I thought you were researching the level of comfort of humans on Venus (Venus surface pressure is more than 75 Earth atmospheres).

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance - While Venus is one of the few known terrestrial bodies with an atmosphere thicker than Earth, I am dealing with hypotheticals. A breathable, earth composition atmosphere, with a thicker atmosphere, and the limit at which humans start to have trouble.

Comment: @GoingFTL - If you need answers, you need research. If you need research, you need funding. As a result, to have a scientific answer (researched and tested) - you need some real problem that was paid to be researched. Do you have in mind any particular problem that was researched by industry or academic science - relevant to your inquiry?

Answer (score 6):

I can’t answer your question with a specific pressure, since symptoms depend on the individual, the rate of descent, time at depth  and lifetime exposure to high pressure.

Symptoms from high pressure can be due to either the breathing gasses or to the pressure itself.

**Gas toxicity:**

Most physiologic and toxic effects of breathing gasses are determined by their partial pressures. Obviously, the sum of all partial pressures must equal the ambient pressure. So when the partial pressure limit of a gas is reached, an inert gas must be added.

1. **Oxygen** toxicity. High concentrations of oxygen, up to 100% at 2 atmospheres (partial pressure of 30psi), can be tolerated for up to a few days. But, as a rule, 100% oxygen cannot be breathed at 1 atmosphere for more than a week without risking inflammation of the lungs. In long term hyperbaric habitats, oxygen partial pressure is usually limited to 6 psi (sea level air is 3.15psi). Toxicity symptoms are related to inflammation of lung tissue
2. **Nitrogen** acts as a general anesthetic (nitrogen narcosis) at partial pressures over about 46psi (sea water equivalent depth of 115 ft breathing compressed air). Mental performance and judgment deteriorate with increasing partial pressure until unconsciousness occurs.
3. **Helium** is added when the total combined tolerated partial pressure of both oxygen and nitrogen is less than the ambient pressure. However, Helium is excitatory for the central nervous system (see high pressure nervous syndrome below) so sometimes the partial pressure of nitrogen must be increased to provide a “general anesthetic” effect to counteract this excitatory tendency.  Helium also causes problems with thermoregulation.

**Pressure symptoms**

1. **Compression arthralgia** (joint pain) occurs during compression (the period of increasing pressure). It tends to improve with time at depth or decompression. It can limit work and depth. There is not a specific depth at which it occurs since it is caused by the change in pressure, not the absolute pressure
2. **Dysbaric osteonecrosis** (bone death). This is a problem with long term exposure to high pressure, as seen in professional divers.
3. **High pressure nervous syndrome** is seen at depths of over 500 feet (about 15 atmospheres) while breathing helium. It results in tremors, memory lapses, visual disturbances and somnolence.
4. **Thermoregulation**. Helium is widely used in saturation diving habitats. The low molecular weight gives high molecular velocity at a given temperature, and therefore rapid conduction of heat (six times that of air). Sometimes dry suits are inflated with Argon (heavy molecular weight, slow heat conduction) to counter the thermoregulation effects of Helium
5. **Breathing resistance** is caused by the increased density of breathing gasses at higher pressure. At sufficient depth, the effort of breathing can limit exercise tolerance and cause buildup of carbon dioxide in the blood. Unfortunately, Argon is particularly dense. This limits its usefulness as an inert gas.

Comment: You are so wrong, partial pressure of oxygen should be lower than 1.4 to 1.6 bar for some hours and lower than 0.5 bar for days.

Comment: Unfortunately, much of this is simply incorrect.

Comment: @Uwe   ...  "Symptoms of toxicity typically begin after ∼12–16 h at 1.0 ATA, 8–14 h at 1.5 ATA, and 3–6 h at 2.0 ATA. Symptoms occur earlier at 2.5 and 3.0 ATA, but are milder since exposure time is limited by neurologic oxygen toxicity." https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5467109/#:~:text=of%20an%20episode.-,Pulmonary%20oxygen%20toxicity,2%2C%20or%20pO2%20increases.

Comment: @fectin ... Please elaborate. If you submit an answer you will have a format for correcting errors you have found.

Comment: The values for oxygen toxicity are valid for hyperbaric oxygen treatment of patients, they are not valid for divers or astronauts. The risk of loosing consciousness is acceptable only for patients under supervision by medical personnel.

Comment: So oxygen is the main limiter, with anything else becoming a problem long after oxygen toxicity is fatal. While that paper doesn't have an exact limit, they didn't observe any oxygen toxicity at 1 week of .55 ATA, which adds up to roughly 2.6 atmospheric pressures with oxygen at 21%- at least if I'm doing these calculations right. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @GoingFTL ... Correct. That corresponds to about 55 feet of water depth which is about the limit for saturation diving on compressed air. (see Aquarius Reef Base underwater habitat at 62 feet). Deeper saturation habitats (over 300 ft depth) are possible with mixed gas.

Comment: @GoingFTL ... to support your figure of .55 atm O2 being tolerated long term, in clinical medicine there is a rule of thumb that patients can tolerate 50% inspired O2 indefinitely without concern for oxygen toxicity.